# ¿Recorrer datos de tablas relacionadas en php?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Tengo las siguientes tablas que están relacionadas:

"**categorías**" con los campos (id, nombre, descripción)

"**productos**" con los campos (id, foto, nombre,descripción, precio, **id_categorías**).

"**variaciones**" con los campos (id, foto, nombre, precio, ***id_productos***).

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar mi producto, a que categoría pertenece y sus respectivas variaciones, para traer los datos ejecuto un **inner join** en mi modelo para unir las 3 tablas y luego en mi controlador recibo esa consulta, pero quiero recorrerla para mostrar los datos.
la consulta es la siguiente:

```
public function viewSingleProductModel($id){
$stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.foto,
    p.nombre,
    p.descripcion,
    p.precio,
    c.nombre as categoria,
    o.foto as variacion_foto,
    o.nombre as variacion_nombre,
    o.precio as variacion_precio
FROM productos as p
INNER JOIN categorias as c ON c.id = p.id_categorías
INNER JOIN variaciones as o ON p.id = o.id_productos
WHERE p.id=:id
");
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
    $stmt->close();
}
}
```

en el controlador he intentado recorrer esa consulta de la siguiente forma: (pero no me ha funcionado)

```
public function viewSingleProductController(){
        if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
            $id=$_GET["id"];
            $reply = CRUDSingleProductsModels::viewSingleProductModel($id);
            foreach($reply as $row){
                echo'
                    <p>categoria: '.$row["categoria"].'</p>
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <img src="core/'.$row["foto"].'" class="img-thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <h2><b>'.$row["nombre"].'</b></h2>
                        <h4 id="price">$'.$row["precio"].' USD</h4>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h6>Descripción</h6>
                            <p>'.$row["descripcion"].'</p>
                        </div>
                ';
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                echo'
                        <!-- aqui van mis variaciones-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                <button class="btn btn-block" id="boton">
                                    <label class="checkeable">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="cap1"/>
                                        <img src="'.$value["variacion_foto"].'" />
                                        <span> '.$value["variacion_nombre"].'</span><b id="extraprice">$'.$value["variacion_precio"].' USD</b>
                                    </label>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- fin variaciones-->
                ';

                echo '
                    </div>
                ':
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

el error que me devuelve en la parte de las variaciones es el siguiente:

imprime 18 veces esto:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'variacion_foto' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\controllers\singleProduct.php on line 32

Warning: Illegal string offset 'variacion_nombre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\controllers\singleProduct.php on line 33

Warning: Illegal string offset 'variacion_precio' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\controllers\singleProduct.php on line 33

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cuando decis que no funciono, podrias explicar que es lo que no funciono?

Comment: en la parte de las variaciones me imprime 18 veces esto:


Warning: Illegal string offset 'variacion_foto' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\controllers\singleProduct.php on line 32

Warning: Illegal string offset 'variacion_nombre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\controllers\singleProduct.php on line 33

Warning: Illegal string offset 'variacion_precio' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\controllers\singleProduct.php on line 33

Comment: Ese error debe ir en la pregunta... y si te da ese error, querra decir que ese campo no esta en esa tabla?

Comment: si están los campos, los renombre en la consulta, solo que no tengo una idea clara de como recorrer las variaciones de mi producto con el foreach, estuve investigando pero aun no encontré alguna forma de hacerlo.